# bind parameter inside a lexical parameter oracle reports builder

Tags: oracle11g, oraclereports

Is there a way to use a bind parameter inside a lexical parameter query something like this?:

```
select col from tbl where col = :bind_param
```

note: the code above is an input in a lexical parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When saying a "lexical query", do you mean a "lexical parameter"?

If I understood you correctly, then yes - you can do that, by setting it in the **After Parameter Form trigger**. (BTW, that's where I set my lexical parameters' values, always).

Open Reports Online Help System and search for "lexical". It is very well described. I believe that this is what you are asking:

> A lexical reference cannot be used to create additional bind variables
>   after the After Form trigger fires. For example, suppose you have a
>   query like the following (note that the WHERE clause is replaced by a
>   lexical reference):
>
> ```
> SELECT ENAME, SAL FROM EMP
>   &where_clause
> ```
>
> If the value of the `where_clause` parameter contains a reference to a
>   bind variable, you must specify the value in the After Form trigger or
>   earlier (*LF). You would get an error if you supplied the following value
>   for the parameter in the Before Report trigger:
>
> ```
> WHERE SAL = :new_bind
> ```
>
> If you supplied this same value in the After Form trigger, the report
>   would run.

(*LF) Now, that's somewhat contradictory - "or earlier" actually *is* the Before Report trigger, so ... take it with caution. As I've said (and I'll repeat it): I set lexical parameters' values in the After Parameter Form. Worked always (for me).

Comment: thanks again bro but you're a bit late. i already figured it out earlier that i can do it in after parameter form haha.

Comment: I'm not late, but you were early :) I was sleeping at the time you posted the question.

Comment: timezone's fault bro